# CI/CD ARM Templates - Should the cloud infrastructure and resources be checked on each deployment?

Tags: azure-devops, azure, infrastructure-as-code

Given a company adopts infrastructure as code deployment model using ARM templates.

Is it a good practice to attempt to re-deploy the ARM templates alongside the application itself ?

If yes what deployment mode (incremental/substitution) should be used and why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if you are doing ARM then follow the replace ideology if you can manage to have things stateless but if not then maybe go via the Terraform route than ARM IMHO